# ANTLR stop at first occurence

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have these rules:

```
while: 'while' expr 'do' program;
if: 'if' expr 'then' program 'else' program;
```

I don't care what `expr` contains, so how can I take everything there until `then` or `do`?

I tried:

```
expr: .*?~('then'|'do');
```

but it is not working. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If the content and structure doesn't matter to you use the token stream instead. Iterate over all tokens (starting at the `while` token until you encounter `do` (and jump over all nested loops). Your parser ensures the input is correct, so it is ok to use the token stream then.